# find files with same name in different directories and count duplicates

Tags: linux, algorithm, bash

I hope you can help me with the following problem. I have 24 directories each containing many (1000's) of files. I would like to find out which combination of directories contains the most number of duplicate (by name only) files. For example if we only consider 4 directories

dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4

with the following directory contents

dir1

> 1.fa 2.fa 3.fa 4.fa 5.fa

dir2

> 1.fa 10.fa 15.fa

dir3

> 1.fa 2.fa 3.fa

dir4

> 1.fa 2.fa 3.fa 5.fa 8.fa 10.fa

Therefore, the combination of directories dir1 and dir4 contain the most duplicate files (4).

The problem becomes quite large with 24 directories so I was thinking that I might use a brute force approach. Something along the lines of

1. count all duplicate files that occur in all 24 directories
2. drop a directory and count the number of duplicate files
3. replace the directory and drop another one then count number
4. repeat for all directories
5. get the subset of 23 directories with max number of duplicate files
6. repeat the above 2-5 and keep the 22 directories with most duplicate files
7. repeat until only 2 directories left
8. choose the combination of directories with the max number of duplicate files

If any one has a way of doing this I would be very grateful for some advice. I thought of using `fdupes` or `diff` but cant figure out how to parse the output and summarise.

Comment: are you limited to shl scripting or can you use Perl/Python?

Comment: I dont have alot of experience with perl or python but am willing to give it a go!

Comment: When you say `which combination of directories...` do you mean `which 2 directories`, or `what is the least number of directories that...`? If there is no limit on the number for your "combination of directories", then the `O(1)` answer is always just to take all directories and that will always contain the most number of duplicate files. If you mean to choose 2 directories, there are clever solutions in `P` time. If you mean to choose the minimum set of directories with the most duplicates, this reduces to the mininum set cover problem and is `NP`

Comment: @sampson-chen thanks for your comment. To clarify, i would like the minimum number of directories with the most duplicates

Comment: are these 24 directories all nested under a single parent directory, or are they scattered about the filesystem?

Comment: @nullrevolution they are all nested under a single parent directory

Comment: please consider adding these important points of information to you main question above. Also, rather than an 8 step "Should I do this"?, consider illustrating your need with required example output. It's hard to be sure of your intent, even with the clarifications. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thank you for your comment. I am new to this (or any forum) so appreciate you pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 4):

I tagged your question with `algorithm` as I am unaware of any existing bash / linux tools that can help you directly solve this problem. The easiest way would be to construct algorithm for this in a programming language such as Python,  C++, or Java instead of using bash shells.

That being said, here's a high level analysis of your problem: At first glance it looks like a mininum set cover problem, but it's actually broken down into 2 parts:

---

**Part 1 - What is the set of files to cover?**

You want to find the combination of directories that cover the most number of duplicate files. But first you need to know what the maximum set of duplicate files are within your 24 directories.

Since the intersection of files between 2 directories is always greater than or equal to the intersection with a 3rd directory, you go through all pairs of directories and find what the maximum intersection set is:

```
(24 choose 2) = 276 comparisons
```

You take the largest intersection set found and use that as the set you are actually trying to cover.

---

**Part 2 - The minimum set cover problem**

This is a [well-studied problem in computer science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), so you are better served reading from [the writings of people much smarter than I](http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18434S06/setcover-tamara.pdf).

The only thing I have to note that it's a [NP-Complete problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), so it's not trivial.

---

This is the best I can do to address the original formulation of your question, but I have a feeling that it's overkill for what you actually need to accomplish. You should consider updating your question with the actual problem that you need to solve.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I was thinking about the brute force approach i outlined above as I dont really need an 'exact' answer, just an idea about which folders to keep to give me the most number of similar files. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Count duplicate file names in shell:

```
#! /bin/sh

# directories to test for
dirs='dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4'

# directory pairs already seen
seen=''

for d1 in $dirs; do
    for d2 in $dirs; do
        if echo $seen | grep -q -e " $d1:$d2;" -e " $d2:$d1;"; then
            : # don't count twice
        elif test $d1 != $d2; then
            # remember pair of directories
            seen="$seen $d1:$d2;"
            # count duplicates
            ndups=`ls $d1 $d2 | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 1' | wc -l`
            echo "$d1:$d2 $ndups"
        fi
    done
# sort decreasing and take the first
done | sort -k 2rn | head -1
```

Answer (score 0):

./count_dups.sh:

```
1 files are duplicated Comparing dir1 to dir2.
3 files are duplicated Comparing dir1 to dir3.
4 files are duplicated Comparing dir1 to dir4.
1 files are duplicated Comparing dir2 to dir3.
2 files are duplicated Comparing dir2 to dir4.
3 files are duplicated Comparing dir3 to dir4.
```

./count_dups.sh | sort -n | tail -1

```
4 files are duplicated Comparing dir1 to dir4.
```

Using the script count_dups.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This assumes (among other things) that the dirs don't have spaces in the names

cd testdirs
declare -a DIRS=(`ls`);

function count_dups {
    DUPS=`ls $1 $2 | sort | uniq -d | wc -l`
    echo "$DUPS files are duplicated comparing $1 to $2."
}

LEFT=0
while [ $LEFT -lt ${#DIRS[@]} ] ; do
    RIGHT=$(( $LEFT + 1 ))
    while [ $RIGHT -lt ${#DIRS[@]} ] ; do
        count_dups ${DIRS[$LEFT]} ${DIRS[$RIGHT]}
        RIGHT=$(( $RIGHT + 1 ))
    done
    LEFT=$(( $LEFT + 1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we create hash table for all of these 24 directories? 
If the filename is just number , the hash function will be very easy to design.

If we can use hash table, it will be faster to search and find duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Just for curiosity, I've done some simple tests: 24 directories with approximately 3900 files in each (a random number between 0 and 9999). Both bash-scripts take around 10 seconds each. Here is a basic python-script doing the same in ~0.2s:

```
#!/usr//bin/python

import sys, os

def get_max_duplicates(path):
    items = [(d,set(os.listdir(os.path.join(path,d)))) \
        for d in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, d))]
    if len(items) < 2: 
        # need at least two directories
        return ("","",0)
    values = [(items[i][0],items[j][0],len(items[i][1].intersection(items[j][1]))) \
        for i in range(len(items)) for j in range(i+1, len(items))]
    return max(values, key=lambda a: a[2])


def main():
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv)==2 else os.getcwd()
    r = get_max_duplicates(path)
    print "%s and %s share %d files" % r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As mentioned by Richard, by using a hash-table (or set in python), we can speed things up. The intersection of two sets is [O(min(len(set_a), len(set_b)))](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) and we have to do `N(N-1)/2=720` comparisons.